# Unable to download large zipped file of cPanel full backup (Chrome download restarts download )

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, backups

I'm trying to download a full backup in the format of `.tar.gz` after using the cPanel Backup Wizard to backup my entire Home directory in File Manager. The size of the file is 31.62 GB.

I'm downloading the file using Chrome browser. However, what happens at some point, say around 10GB - 13GB in the download progress, the browser would just restart the download. So I don't get anywhere.

I’m on a shared host server (Linux OS) plan, as per the naming of my hosting plan. My host provider is Godaddy. The staff member who I was speaking to, wasn't much of help unfortunately. He said something like, the browser has a download limit. So it's not practical to download a backup on cPanel, for large files. Then they asked: “why do I want to download my backup”. Frankly I didn't want to tell them - “because I want to migrate to another host provider”, because I suspected that they would either try to sell me things to stay with them, or wouldn't help at all.

Does anyone know what the issue is and if there's a workaround?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't download it through your browser. Download it via FTP instead.

Comment: @JohnConde snap!

Comment: Sorry for my late reply John and Steve. I still haven't tried it yet, as I've got some work & deadlines to meet. As soon as I try your suggestion(s) I'll get back to you with an update and upvote/approve answer if all goes well. Thank you both so much for your response and answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can find or change the location of backups in cpanel's Configure Backup Directory section of Backup Configuration interface `Home > Backup > Backup Configuration`

Once you know the location of your file, rather than using a browser, use an FTP client such as [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I use both directadmin and cpanel. Directadmin download via browser works no problem. This is definitely a cpanel issue and has been for some years. Pretty hopeless really that its been so long without a fix.